# Using tidyr and regex to create two columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to separate one column of data that contains a code and a place name into two separate columns. I tried using `tidyr`'s separate command, but ran into some difficulties with the regex (I haven't used them before and am not able to figure out what I did wrong/how regex really works).

The data are pretty consistent in terms of format. Most observations start with a code and are followed by a location. Occasionally there is an observation that is just a location (no code). Here is a sample of the data:

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
obs  name
1    01-220 location 1
2    05-23 town 3
3    District 2"), header = T)
```

I use the following code:

```
df <- df %>% separate(name, into = c("location_code", "location_name"), sep = "([0-9] [A-z])")
```

Resulting in (notice that the last number from location_code and first letter from location_name are missing):

```
obs   location_code    location_name
1     01-22           ocation 1
2     05-2            own 3
3     District 2       NA
```

My desired output is:

```
# obs   location_code    location_name
# 1     01-220           location 1
# 2     05-23            town 3
# 3     NA               District 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the `sep` with a regex lookaround.

```
separate(df, name, into = c("location_code", "location_time"),
                                  "(?<=([0-9] )|\\b)(?=[A-Za-z])")
#   obs location_code location_time
#1   1       01-220     location 1
#2   2        05-23         town 3
#3   3                  District 2
```

---

Or with `extract`

```
extract(df, name, into = c("location_code", "location_time"), "([0-9-]*)\\s*(.*)")
#  obs location_code location_time
#1   1        01-220    location 1
#2   2         05-23        town 3
#3   3                  District 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(obs = 1:3, name = c("01-220 location 1", "05-23 town 3", 
 "District 2")), .Names = c("obs", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: NJ with `extract` I was trying something similar but couldn't get the last row right

Comment: @DavidArenburg One thing it misses is the NA.  Here it gives `""`

Comment: Hi @akrun, your use of `separate` solves my issue of the last number and first letter being deleted, and the district appearing in the location_code column. However, it introduces a new problem of anything after the first space in location_name being cut, eg this is the result c("location", "town") rather than c("location 1", "town 3"). The `extract` code works perfectly though!

Comment: @kongbian I didn't had that problem based on the example data in my post